# About constant velocity linear motion with zero net force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

Suppose the situation where an object undergoes linear motion at a constant velocity on a frictionless surface. This motion is often introduced as inertial motion, which is the motion described with Newton's first law. On the other hand, suppose the situation where a person applies a force to an object on a surface with friction, adjusting the force to balance the kinetic frictional force and causing the object to undergo linear motion at a constant velocity (here assuming no torque).

In terms of the fact that net force exerted to the object is zero, I know there has been recognition that the motion of the latter case can be interpreted as inertial motion according to Newton's first law. However, is such motion really an example of inertial motion? Such motion seems to be rather different from the motion of the former case (close to Galileo's original thought experiment in which the essence of inertial motion is highlighted in idealized situation with no friction). Or is it just a problem of how we define inertial motion?

Answer (score 0):

Friction is doing work on the object in order to slow it down.  The force and work applied to the object to keep it moving at a constant velocity is equal in magnitude and opposite in direction to the friction force such that there is no net force acting on the object.  This is equivalent to the case of frictionless constant velocity, where there is also no net force acting on the object.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I understand the applied force is opposite in direction to the kinetic frictional force. As for the work, the applied force does posiitve work and the frictional force does negative work, so the energy of the object is being dissipated, but the kinetic energy is kept constant, is this recognition is OK?

Comment: The kinetic energy of the object isn't being dissipated because the applied force is doing enough work to exactly offset the friction work.  If the object has another form of energy (e.g., chemical potential energy), that energy is not being dissipated, based on your problem description.

Comment: Thank you for explanations. So in this situation, the work is certainly done by the applied force and the frictional force, but they are canceled. In this case, is it OK to say the conservation law of the mechanical energy hold?

Comment: Conservation of the mechanical energy doesn't hold when involving non-conservative force like frictional force, even if external force applied is equal to frictional force. Energy dissipation does occur in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, such motion really is inertial motion. Even in the case of a frictionless surface there is still a gravitational force and normal force. Inertial motion is a description of the motion of the object, not the force(s) acting on it.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I understand your points. In the former motion, as you pointed out, normal force balanced with gravitational force results in zero net force. Then, why the latter motion (In addition to balanced force in vertical direction, applied force balanced with frictional force in horizontal direction) is not often introduced as a typical example of inertial motion? Of course, I found such example in several sources, but in fact I often see the uniform linear motion of frictionless floor as a typical example of inertial motion (such as curling stones and ice hockey pucks).

Comment: @kzo The ice hockey pucks are used as an example because they are familiar to ordinary life and uncomplicated. Balanced forces in the horizontal direction is also inertial motion, but perhaps confusing for newcomers.

Comment: Yes, I see, the both motions is inertial motion. I agree the pucks case is simple and uncomplicated, whereas the balanced force in direction of movement is confusing for newcomers. I think frictional force makes the situation to be more complicated. In my question, two forces are assumed to be balanced perfectly, so I agree it is inertial motion. In real situation, even in the simple case, it is impossible to completely remove frictional force, but it is simpler than this balanced force case. The existence of the surrouding finite forces makes the inertial motion a little bit blurring..

Answer (score 0):

Note that in your example before the pushing force is applied the object was at rest. A force exceeding the maximum possible static friction force was initially required to accelerate the object and change its speed. per Newton’s 1st law. Since the static friction force is normally greater than the kinetic friction force, the applied force had to be reduced to equal the kinetic friction force and have constant velocity.

Now the object is moving in a straight line at constant speed. Its motion is inertial because as long as the net force is zero,  per Newton’s 1st law it will remain in motion at constant speed. If either the pushing force or friction force were to be eliminated there would be a net force causing the object to change speed (decelerate) again per Newton’s 1st law.

So you can think of inertial motion as either resisting a change in speed before being set into motion, or resisting a change in speed while in motion, the latter irrespective of whether or not forces are involved, as long the net force is zero.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for answering. Just let me ask, "1st law" appearing in your sentence "accelerate the object and change its speed. per Newton’s 1st law", "causing the object to change speed (decelerate) again per Newton’s 1st law". Are these intended to be 2nd law?

Comment: Newton’s first state that an object at rest or moving in a straight line at constant speed tends to stay at rest or move in a straight line at constant speed unless acted upon by a net external force. That’s what I’m referring to. Newton’s second law provides the relationship between the net force and the acceleration of the object as $F_{net}=ma$.

Comment: OK, I understand that point. I mean If a non-zero net force is applied, an object will undergo accelerated motion. This is a situation described by 2nd law, isn'it? You write "a net force causing the object to change speed(decelerate) again per Newton's 1st law."..

Comment: @kzo the situation is described by both. The difference is the second law describes the mathematical relationship between the net force and acceleration whereas the first law does not

Comment: I see, so are you describing the motion of accelerating object in terms of a contrapositional proposition of the 1st law? (if an object is not in uniform linear motion, there would be non-zero net force)

Comment: @kzo Not sure I see the application of "contrapositional proposition" here, but yes if an object is not in uniform linear motion there must be a non zero net force.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I understood what you said. Rerturning to my original question, the 1st law tells that an object will maintain (or remain in) stationary or constant velocity linear motion unless acted upon by a net external force. So the motion in the latter case, while I understand 1st law hold, I can' help but get an impression that a person is "maintaining" the motion, not an object itself. This is maybe just impresstion and not irrelevant with physics which defining the motion is inertial or not. I would like to hear your opion.

Comment: @kzo “I can't help but get an impression that a person is ‘maintaining’ the motion, not an object itself.” Maintaining the objects motion means the objects speed does not change, i.e., it neither increases nor decreases. The person doesn’t maintain its speed, it only keeps the object’s motion from decreasing due to friction. The friction force also doesn’t maintain its speed, it only keeps the object’s motion from increasing due to the person.  When the net force is zero the objects motion is maintained due to its inertia, just as if both the person and friction were not there.

Comment: at Bob D "just as if both the person and friction were not there", so I guess your saying is that the motion is essentially same with the case of frictionless surface, is that right? In fact, in order for the object to keep moving in constant linear motion, the person must apply force and do work (the kinetic friction do negative work), but such energestics is not relevant to the 1st law?

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed inertial motion. Note that all inertial frames are indistinguishable from one another - there is no possible experiment you can do that will reveal "which" inertial frame you are in.

Suppose you are on a train. You do some experiments are find that everything obeys the usual laws of physics, and requires no ficticious forces to explain. From this, you can infer you are in an inertial frame, but it is impossible to say which inertial frame you are in - you might be on a train that's coasting down a truly frictionless track, or you might be on a train whose engine is struggling to counter friction and keep the train at a constant speed. All your experiments will tell you that you are moving at a constant speed, but it won't indicate what is causing your constant speed.

As long as something moves with constant velocity, it is inertial. It doesn't matter what causes that constant velocity, whether it is a precise balance of many forces, or a complete lack of forces.

Comment: You are talking about an inertial coordinate system. I am talking about the state of motion intended by the first law. When the expression zero net force is in the 1st law, the concept of net force actually comes from the 2nd law, which is implicitly assumed in the 1st law. If inertial motion is defined as motion obeying the first law, OK, then constant velocity linear motion with zero net force is inertial motion, I was told by you all. But in effect, it is inertial motion in combination with the 2nd law. The 1st law in Principia does not include net force zero.

Answer (score -1):

I think your question is very interesting and important. Perhaps many people would misunderstand the difference between intertia motion and intertia coordinate/frame. As you mention, even though the substance moving at a constant speed along a line does not always obey the law of inertia, because the substance with a motor/engine against any friction dissipates the energy to the surroundings, which is critically different from the ideal inertial motion. However, as someone said in a previous answer, such a substance provides an inertial coordinate even if it is helped by the engine... Anyway, we have to distinguish between genuine inertial motion of the substance intself (indentical to the law of inertia), inertial coordinate provided by the artificial linear-constant-speed motion, and inertial charcteristics that are frequently obeserved in an actual experience, e.g., in an accelerated train.